# What could be the reason an ATX PSU triggers OVP?

Tags: power-supply, repair, atx

I have a broken MARS MP600 PSU that I am trying to repair.

Everything looks good but when I turn it on (grounding PS_ON) the outputs do not maintain the voltage.
The output signals go to the rated voltage, start increasing softly and then everything turns off, this happens in a period of ~350ms. I suspect that the power supply supervisor (P/N WT7502V) is triggering the OVP.

This is what I measured in the WT7502V pins:
[image]

- 12V pin starts in 11.6V a stops at 13.47V (there is an anti-reverse diode because it is also connected to the standby 5V).
- 5V pin starts in 5.17V and stops at 5.91V
- 3V pin maintain the 3.3V during this time. (not shown)

The OVP protection for WT7502V are:

- **12V**: min 12.8V typ 13.4V max 13.9V
- **5V**: min 5.7V typ 5.85V max 6V

I also tried to solder capacitors parallel to the ones in the outputs (without removing the originals), it gave me ~50ms extra but it did not solve the problem.

Any idea where could the  problem be or next steps to follow?

Comment: What loads have you placed on the various outputs?

Comment: try 2A dummy load on 5V then 12V using anything handy, power transistor, light bulb etc

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now. I originally tried 4.7kOhms in 12V but did not improved significantly. After your comments I tried 1kOhm in each output and it keep it alive for ~45s (do not have a 2A load available right now). The best part is that it happens that the fan load is enough to keep it alive...

The moral of the story , not everything you find in trash is necesarily broken. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing under load? This may well just be a characteristic behaviour of your PSU and not a fault per-se.

When operating under normal load switch mode power supplies operate in "continuous conduction mode". In this mode the output voltage is determined mostly by the input voltage and the duty cycle with load current only having a relatilvey minor impact (with ideal components it would have no impact), so the drive controller only has to make relatively minor adjustments to account for varying load and input voltage.

However under very light or no load switchmode converters that use diodes (which is most of them) enter what is known as discontinuous mode. In this mode output voltage is strongly linked to load current and far more radical changes in duty cycle are needed to compensate.

This is especially problematic for power supplies that try to derive multiple output rails from different taps on one controller/transformer as the duty cycle needed for one output may not be the same as for other outputs.

The result is many switchmode power supplies, particularly older designs or designs with multiple outputs, have a minimum load specification below which they will not operate properly.